# Generate single text file in nested for loop

Tags: r, for-loop

I am writing R code to generate 1 stacked text file that I will run in separate geochemistry modeling software. To do this, I am pulling data from another text file, where each line of the file is a different sample. Instead of making individual text files, I want to make one whole text file, basically where I rbind() each samples output. I have the code so far to loop through individual text files, but how can I make one text file without having to re-import all the files I've made. Re-importing isn't a good option because it is not easily read by R. Code below. Thank you

```
set.seed(12)
data <- matrix(sample(12*15), nrow = 12, ncol = 15)

out <- (matrix(nrow=5, ncol=1))

for (i in 1: nrow(data)) {
   out[1,1] <- paste('SOLUTION 00', rownames(data[i,]), "   ", data[i,1], sep="")
   out[2,1] <- paste("temp     21")
   out[3,1] <- paste("pH","     ", ((data[i,2]) - 7) / ((-1) / (((25 + 273.15) 
      / 298) * 59)) * ((-1) / (((21 + 273.15) / 298) * 59)) + 7, sep = "")
   out[4,1] <- paste("units    umol/L")
   out[5,1] <- paste("Cl", "       ", data[i,3], sep="")
  file.name <- paste("00",rownames(data[i,]), "_", data[i,1], ".txt", sep="")
  write.table(out, file=filename, sep="", row.names=FALSE, col.names=FALSE, na=" ", quote=FALSE)
} # At this point, how do I make one giant text file, not individual text files?
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set up  `out`, your output matrix, so that it stores all the results. It just requires a bit of thinking about how to set up the indexes:

```
# 5 rows in out for each row of data
out <- (matrix(nrow=5 * nrow(data), ncol=1))

for (i in 1:nrow(data)) {
    # Start at 1 for i = 1, 6 for i = 2, etc.
    first_row = 5 * (i - 1) + 1
    out[first_row, 1] <- paste('SOLUTION 00', rownames(data[i,]), "   ", data[i,1], sep="")
    out[first_row + 1, 1] <- paste("temp     21")
    out[first_row + 2, 1] <- paste("pH","     ", ((data[i,2]) - 7) / ((-1) / (((25 + 273.15) 
                                                                  / 298) * 59)) * ((-1) / (((21 + 273.15) / 298) * 59)) + 7, sep = "")
    out[first_row + 3,1] <- paste("units    umol/L")
    out[first_row + 4,1] <- paste("Cl", "       ", data[i,3], sep="")
} 

# Write all results at once
write.table(out, file="AllRecords.txt", sep="", row.names=FALSE, col.names=FALSE, na=" ", quote=FALSE)
```

Answer (score 0):

You have it writing in the loop. If you move it out of the loop it will make one text file.

```
set.seed(12)
data <- matrix(sample(12*15), nrow = 12, ncol = 15)

out <- (matrix(nrow=5, ncol=1))

for (i in 1: nrow(data)) {
  out[1,1] <- paste('SOLUTION 00', rownames(data[i,]), "   ", data[i,1], sep="")
  out[2,1] <- paste("temp     21")
  out[3,1] <- paste("pH","     ", ((data[i,2]) - 7) / ((-1) / (((25 + 273.15) 
                                                            / 298) * 59)) * ((-1) / (((21 + 273.15) / 298) * 59)) + 7, sep = "")
  out[4,1] <- paste("units    umol/L")
  out[5,1] <- paste("Cl", "       ", data[i,3], sep="") 
}
 file.name <- paste("00",rownames(data[i,]), "_", data[i,1], ".txt", sep="")
 write.table(out, file=file.name, sep="", row.names=FALSE,    col.names=FALSE, na=" ", quote=FALSE)
```